# eval scheme function with quote

Tags: scheme, let

I am trying to evaluate a formula in scheme:

```
(define formula '(if (or (equal? '?country 'United-States) (equal? '?country 'England))
                  #t
                  #f))
(define (eval-formula formula)
  (eval `(let ([?country 'United-States])
           (display formula) (newline)
           (display ?country) (newline)
           ,formula)))

(eval-formula formula)
```

reading http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html that should return #t but when I run it, it returns #f. Could you please tell me what I misunderstood?

I tried also:

```
(define formula '(if (or (equal? '?country 'United-States) (equal? '?country 'England))
                  #t
                  #f))
(define ?country 'United-States)
(eval formula)
```

but I got the same result.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition of `formula` you have quoted `?country` - that is the mistake.  Here is the behavior (note, my Scheme's `eval` requires an additional `environment` argument):

```
(define formula '(if (or (equal? ?country 'United-States) (equal? ?country 'England))
                  #t
                  #f))

(define (eval-formula formula)
  (eval `(let ([?country 'United-States])
           (display formula) (newline)
           (display ?country) (newline)
           ,formula)
    (interaction-environment)))

> (eval-formula formula)
(if (or (equal? ?country 'United-States) (equal? ?country 'England)) #t #f)
United-States
#t
```

There are a couple of things to make this better.  You don't really need the `if` (you'll get `#t` or `#f` as the result of `or`).  You can pass an additional argument to `eval-formula` for the name of the country.  Like so (with `display` removed):

```
> (define (eval-formula formula country)
  (eval `(let ([?country ',country]) ,formula)
    (interaction-environment)))
> (eval-formula formula 'United-States)
#t
> (eval-formula formula 'England)
#t
> (eval-formula formula 'Japan)
#f
```

If, in fact, you are given `formula` with `(quote ?country)` then you can produce a new `formula` with `?country` unquoted with:

```
(define (unquoting identifiers expression)
  (if (null? expression)
      '()
      (let ((next (car expression)))
        (cons (cond ((not (pair? next)) next)
                    ((not (null? next))
                     (if (and (eq? 'quote (car next))
                              (member (cadr next) identifiers))
                         (cadr next) ; unquote here
                         (unquoting identifiers next)))
                    (else 'error))
          (unquoting identifiers (cdr expression))))))

 (set! formula (unquoting '(?country) formula)
```

Comment: The problem is that I receive some formulas and some values for variables  (the ones that start with ?) and I have to return true or false. I tried t debug it and it evaluates: (if (or (equal? (quote ?country) (quote United-States)) (equal? (quote ?country) (quote England))) #t #f) . I am trying to remove that "quote" in front of ?country.

Comment: My question is how I can unquote ?country

Comment: The only option that I can see it to rewrite `formula` to replace `(quote ?country)` with just `?country`.  If you try to redefine `quote` then that redefinition will apply to `(quote United-States)` and to `(quote England)` and cause evaluation problems.